# In Codeigniter How to check if the uploaded file is actually a pdf or jpg or png?

Tags: php

In Codeigniter How to check if the uploaded file is actually a pdf or jpg or png? Because, if we upload an .exe file with .pdf extension then also it gets uploaded without any problem. So, it there a proper way to actually check the file and its content to be able to determine whether it is actually a pdf or exe. Because with just the file extension anything can be uploaded. Please, help me find a proper solution for this. Is there any native php function through which we can achieve this. If so a sample code might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **mime_content_type()** function which is in built in php it provides actual content type even if the extension is changed
[php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

```
<?php
echo mime_content_type('abcd.pdf') //application/pdf
?>
```

checking mime_content_type while uploading

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if(in_array($mimetype, array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'))) {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/whatever/something/imagedir/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
   echo 'OK';

} else {
    echo 'It is not an image';
}
```

Comment: mime_content_type will only work after uploading the file right? So after uploading the file mime_content_type will check if the file is wrong we will have to delete it or else its fine. Am i right?

Comment: no you can do it while uploading i am updating my answer for upload code

Comment: Just to clarify, this code is technically after the file is uploaded - it's on your server, just in a temporary location. But anything before then can't be trusted anyway - the user could just lie to you about what they're about to upload.

Comment: Also, it's worth knowing what this is checking so you know how far to trust it. Most file formats start with a few bytes declaring the format, and setting some parameter; this function has a database of those, and returns the most probably match. It doesn't guarantee that the file is *valid* for the given type (it might just be the header followed by junk to fill your server up), and it is sometimes possible to craft files which can be interpreted in more than one way.

Comment: @IMSoP what would be an ideal solution then ?

Comment: @sparshturkane Well, if you want to be really sure, the only way is to load the data from the file, and resave it. As long as the library you load it with doesn't have any exploitable bugs, of course. I guess what I'm saying is that there is no single solution that is 100% safe in all cases, so it's important to be aware of the limitations of the solution you choose. For many cases, this is probably sufficient, but it's not magic (despite the name of the database used).

Comment: @IMSoP Could you be a bit more specific with your solution, please. I mean could you explain in simple language possible.

Comment: @user2871257 It was more an example than a solution. If you can load a JPEG image and resize it, it's clearly a valid JPEG file, and if you discard the original, there would need to be some very complicated attack to still end up with anything other than the image data. It's like saying "how do I make my house burglar-proof" - you can keep going forever, but the important thing is to understand what the mechanisms you're using do and don't give you, so you can judge whether they are good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check **real file type** and **given file type** like this:

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$file = $_FILES['userfile'];

// given file type
$gftype=pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);;

// real file type
$rftype = explode('/',mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']))[1];


if($gftype === $rftype){
    if (! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        echo "Error";           
    }else{
        echo "Success";             
    }
}else{
    echo 'This is not real extension';
}
```

Comment: but this only checks the extension. Try uploading an exe file after changing its extension. It gets uploaded without any issue. The CI configs you mentioned above doesn't works. It only checks the extension not the authenticity of the file.